# Determinant proof using its properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove without expanding:
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}bc&a^2&a^2\\b^2&ac&b^2\\c^2&c^2 & ab\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}ac&bc&ab\\bc&ab&ac\\ab&ac&bc\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

---

Tried to multiply by 'abc' in all rows then take common factors.

Tried to expand determinant into two determinants.

I used the determinant properties shown here: http://www.vitutor.com/alg/determinants/properties_determinants.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe I missed something, but why don't you just take the determinant of both matrices and show they give the same result?

Comment: @Mattos because The problem stated that I must use determinant properties, sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: Oh ok. Well see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html), equation $(32)$, I think it may help using the 6 statements above it.

Comment: Have you tried the property that $\det AB = \det A\det B$ Perhaps you can multiply both sides by some matrix to make them equal

Comment: @DanRobertson That's the first thing I've tried, looked reasonable but didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We check that the property holds when one of $a,b,c$ is zero.  Now assume $a,b,c$ are all non-zero.

We divide the columns by $bc$, $ac$, and $ab$, respectively, and multiply the rows by $bc$, $ac$, and $ab$ respectively.  This gives

$$\begin{vmatrix}bc&a^2&a^2\\b^2&ac&b^2\\c^2&c^2 & ab\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}bc&ab&ac\\ab&ac&bc\\ac&bc&ab\end{vmatrix}$$
then we cycle the rows to obtain $$=\begin{vmatrix}ac&bc&ab\\bc&ab&ac\\ab&ac&bc\end{vmatrix}.$$